# Clipboard API for JsonTree

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to copy my settings, which are JSON to clipboard

```
const settings = {
      "id": "1",
      "properties": {
          "conjunction": "AND",
          "not": false
      },
      "children": {
          "1": {
              "type": "userSettings",
              "properties": {
                  "field": "name",
                  "operator": "equal",
                  "value": [
                      "Foo"
                  ],
                  "valueSrc": [
                      "value"
                  ],
                  "valueType": [
                      "text"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  });
```

`navigator.clipboard.write(settings)` is causing the following error:

```
Argument of type 'JsonTree' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClipboardItems'.
Type 'JsonGroup' is missing the following properties from type 'ClipboardItem[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

But I really need it to be JsonTree, as above settings are hardcoded, but in reality I'd like to copy my settings from one view and paste into another as they are, meaning in the format of JsonTree. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

First issue with my code is that clipboard.write() needs ClipboardItem, which is not supported by Firefox.

However, just to see if the desired result is reachable, I tried it out. First step would be to create a string, case as written here [clipboard-apis/#writing-to-clipboard](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#writing-to-clipboard) there are only three types supported: text/plain, text/html, image/png. So there is no way I can write a json to the clipboard for now. So the code is the following

```
const string = JSON.stringify(filterTree)
navigator.clipboard.write([
  new ClipboardItem({
   'text/plain': new Blob([string], {
    type: 'text/plain',
   }),
  }),
 );
```

The better way is however to use `navigator.clipboard.writeText(JSON.stringify(settings))` as it does the same, but needs less code and is supported by all browsers.